# Definir o nome do input select a partir do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, pdo

Como faço para que apareça a descrição do item(que vem do banco) no select ao invés da frase "Selecione a Conta patrimonial"
quero que apareça o : $listar3["DES_CONTA_PATRIMONIAL"]  referente ao item selecionado.

```
<select class="form-control" name="contaPatrimonial" onchange="this.form.submit();" <?php if(!isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { ?> hidden  <?php } ?>  >
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione a Conta patrimonial</option>

                       <?php
                            $linha3 = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach($linha3 as $listar3){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $listar3["CONTA_PATRIMONIAL"]; ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($listar3["DES_CONTA_PATRIMONIAL"]);?> </option>

                        <?php } ?>    
                </select>
```

> Banco

```
if ( isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) {
    $var1 = $_GET["revenda"];
    $query = ("SELECT REVENDA, CONTA_PATRIMONIAL, DES_CONTA_PATRIMONIAL FROM AFX_CONTA_PATRIMONIAL WHERE REVENDA like :rev "); 
    $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt3->bindValue(':rev', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt3->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das varias formas possíveis.

```
<select class="form-control" name="contaPatrimonial" id="contaPatrimonial" onchange="this.form.submit();" <?php if(!isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { ?> hidden  <?php } ?>  >
    <option disabled selected value="">Selecione algo</option>
    <?php
    $linha3 = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($linha3 as $listar3){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $listar3["CONTA_PATRIMONIAL"]; ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($listar3["DES_CONTA_PATRIMONIAL"]);?> </option>

    <?php } ?>    
</select>

<script>
    $("#contaPatrimonial").val("<?php echo isset($_GET["contaPatrimonial"]) ? $_GET["contaPatrimonial"] : ''?>");
</script>
```

Comment: Nao rolou.. o select ficou com varias repetições de resultados e ja ta vindo com um item do banco pré-definido ..

Comment: Ops! faltou uma coisa.

Comment: eu gostaria de manter a frase "Selecione a conta.." e depois que o usuário selecionar a pagina vai atualizar e o select ficar com o resultado selecionado

Comment: Já adicionei o que faltava, desculpa a falha!

Comment: deu quase certo.. agora o select ta ficando sempre com o primeiro resultado

Comment: todos os options estão iguais?

Comment: não.. estão mostrando os resultados certo.. mas quando a pagina atualiza o select fica selecionado no primeiro item e não no qual eu selecionei

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92849/discussion-between-leonardo-barros-and-fernando-fefu).